# Export specific oracle packages (specification and body) from sql prompt

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We have to change existing packages but before we make any change we need to take backup of already (existing) packages in log/sql/text file. 
I would like to take backup of only those packages which we are going to change during release. 
We don't have SQL developer or any UI tool. We can run from SQL prompt.

Assume there are 3 packages owned by user 'usr33'
package names
usr33_pkg135
usr33_pkg234 
usr33_pkg456

Is it possible? 
if yes, how?

Comment: Why do you tag "oracle-sqldeveloper" if you don't have such tool?

Comment: If somebody using sqldeveloper know the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One option** is to use `DBMS_METADATA` package, such as

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PACKAGE', 'USR33_PKG135', 'USR33') result
from dual;
```

**Another one** is to select text from `USER_SOURCE`:

```
select text from user_source where name = 'USR33_PKG135'
order by type, line;
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen these options but how I can export(save) them in text/log/sql files from sql prompt?

Comment: I think the challenge is: how to format the output in a way that you don't get any additional headers, echos, line breaks, etc. Otherwise it will be hard to use the result as a "backup". IDE's like SLQ Developer makes your life much easier for this kind of task.

Comment: As it's production  environment, we aren't allowed to use UI tools.. In SQL command everything is logged... We have no choice to use SQL prompt.

Comment: AAD, you'd **spool** result you get from a SELECT statement into a (TXT) file. SPOOL is a SQL*Plus command.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the source code of the packages by using dbms_metadata:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type=> 'PACKAGE', name=> ?, schema=> ?) from dual
```